# How to unlock iphone 5s?

Tags: unlock

I was given an iPhone 5S for christmas and looks like it is locked to AT&T. How do i unlock it so I can use it overseas? I have looked online but there is no answer except for these suspicious IMEI unlock services. Thanks

Comment: the best bet is taking it either to apple, or calling AT&T for them to unlock it

Comment: I'm locking it as it is an example off-topic question. See [Why we're not customer support for company X or product Y](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y)